# How to allow EC2 instance permission to access backup.sql.gz file on my computer to import sql database to Amazon RDS

Tags: amazon-ec2, file-permissions, database-backups, permission-denied

I'm currently following the steps in the AWS tutorial "Importing Data to an Amazon RDS MYSQL or MariaDB DB Instance with Reduced Downtime" (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/MySQL.Procedural.Importing.NonRDSRepl.html#MySQL.Procedural.Importing.Copy.Database). I am currently stuck in using the following command in my Windows 10 CMD to copy a compressed database backup file from my computer to an EC2 instance:

```
scp -r -i MyKeyName.pem backup.sql.gz ec2-user@myEC2IPV4Domain:/backup.sql.gz
```

I am getting the following error:

```
scp: /backup.sql.gz: Permission denied
```

In an attempt to fix this, I've tried editing the security properties of the file to allow everyone full access to this file instead of just the my user account. That didn't work. And I've tried using:

```
chmod 0400 backup.sql
```

via Bash, then used:

```
gzip backup.sql
```

to get the sql.gz file. Neither of the two methods worked. Using chmod is what was suggested by the tutorial and a related troubleshooting tutorial (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/TroubleshootingInstancesConnecting.html) for any permission errors to access the backup sql file or the MyKeyName.pem file. Using chmod worked to get my EC2 instance access to the pem file (i.e., I successfully troubleshooted Error: Unprotected Private Key File, Permission denied (publickey)), but it doesn't seem like its working on the sql file or its compressed gz file. Any help in figuring out how to successfully copy the backup file to my EC2 instance will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't expect `ec2-user` to have permission to write to `/`. Use another path such as `/tmp/` or `/home/ec2-user/`

```
scp -r -i MyKeyName.pem backup.sql.gz ec2-user@myEC2IPV4Domain:/home/ec2-user/backup.sql.gz
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but got the same error message. Is there any default folder you can suggest I try leaving the backup file in? Is there any way I can edit the security settings in the properties of the file to allow an external ec2 instance full access to the file?